# Can I call sbatch recursively?

Tags: slurm, sbatch

I want to run a program that runs and creates a checkpoint file. Then I want to run several variant configurations that all start from that checkpoint.

For example, if I run:

```
sbatch -n 1 -t 12:00:00 --mem=16g program.sh
```

And `program.sh` looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

./set_checkpoint

sbatch -n 1 -t 12:00:00 --mem=16g cpt_restore_config1.sh
sbatch -n 1 -t 12:00:00 --mem=16g cpt_restore_config2.sh
sbatch -n 1 -t 12:00:00 --mem=16g cpt_restore_config3.sh
sbatch -n 1 -t 12:00:00 --mem=16g cpt_restore_config4.sh
```

Does this implement the desired effect?

Comment: I would be interested to know if you actually managed to run this. I tried with a similar script and it didn't work. I don't think it's possible to just sbatch this type of script as suggested in the answer below.

Comment: @MichelePellegrino Yep! I use it all the time in my work. What's the error that you have?

Comment: Well, the error is simply that calling the script with `sbatch program.sh` literally yields no output. No job is started and I don't even get any output in the standard error.

Comment: Is this dependent on the contents of program.sh? Does it work without making the recursive call (i.e., just stating `echo Hello world`)? I'm wondering if there is a small error going on here, because this behavior seems odd and inconsistent with what I have experienced.

Comment: I confirm: tried to run `echo hello-world > test-$SLURM_JOB_PARTITION.txt` and submit to three different partitions using a script similar to yours. Nothing in the slurm output and error, no test output file created...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general this is not needed. You can allocate all the resources you want in main job script and use resources for specific task with `srun`. Here is a basic example.

```bash
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --nodes=2
#SBATCH --ntasks=8
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=2
#SBATCH --time=01:00:00

module load some_module
srun -n 4 -c 2 ./my_program arg1 arg2
srun -n 4 -c 2 ./my_other_program arg1 arg2
```

Note that we allocated 8 CPUs and used 4 for each task. Here, the two `srun` tasks will run sequentially. To make it run in parallel, you can use this trick.

```bash
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --nodes=2
#SBATCH --ntasks=8
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=2
#SBATCH --time=01:00:00

srun -n 4 -c 2 ./my_program arg1 arg2 &
srun -n 4 -c 2 ./my_other_program arg1 arg2 &

wait
```

Just keep in mind this might not work in several cases. I would suggest using a logger and redirect the `STDOUT` and `STDERR` to a file. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5916874/14598633) is a simple example.

Alternatively, if your tasks are using a single file with different set of parameters, I suggest using [argument parsing](https://www.datacamp.com/tutorial/argument-parsing-in-python). In Python, I generally use [Hydra](https://hydra.cc/)'s [joblib](https://hydra.cc/docs/plugins/joblib_launcher/) extension. It gives you parallelism capability out of the box.

Comment: Much better explanation. Tested and runs on my end as well, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments, it seems that sbatch is not guaranteed to work recursively for some reason. I've recently encountered similar issues, and I could get around the limitation by running my main script from the same shell I'm launching it from. In your case, this would mean using `source program.sh` instead of `sbatch program.sh`.