# How to submit multiple independent tasks via SLURM?

Tags: jobs, slurm

I have a large amount of computation chunks which I would like to run in parallel on a SLURM cluster. Each chunk reads inputs from files and writes outputs to separate files - there is no communication between chunks and therefore chunks do not need to run at the same time. I would like to spread the chunks across nodes and CPUs. Each computation chunk requires only one CPU (it is single-threaded), so the limit of parallel chunk computation on one node is given by the amount of available RAM on each node.

Note: I use the term "computation chunk" to avoid confusion with the SLURM terms "job" and "task".

What is the best way to send the computation chunks to the cluster via SLURM?

I assume that it is not a good idea to submit a job requesting multiple nodes, i.e. setting `--nodes` to a value larger than 1. This would require multiple nodes to be available at the same time, which could increase the waiting time in queue.

I could submit multiple jobs or use [job arrays](https://slurm.schedmd.com/job_array.html) to submit multiple jobs at once. But how can I run multiple computation chunks on one node?
Can multiple jobs run on the same node?

If I set `--ntasks` to the number of computation chunks I need to run and `--ntasks-per-node` to the number of cores on a node, would SLURM automatically spread the processes across nodes? If yes, would these nodes be requested synchronous, i.e. causing a longer queuing time?

As far as I understand, I can use `--ntasks` and `srun` to run a command multiple times (also without use of MPI) on one node. But how would each process know which chunk to compute? Is there something like the env variable `SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID` for tasks?

Is there any difference from using a shell loop in the script to using `--ntasks`?

[This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51139711/hpc-cluster-select-the-number-of-cpus-and-threads-in-slurm-sbatch) gives a very good overview of the implications of the option `--ntasks` and `--ntasks-per-node`, but it does not really answer my questions.

Comment: This might also help. https://stackoverflow.com/a/76912579/14598633

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But how can I run multiple computation chunks on one node? Can multiple jobs run on the same node?

Yes. Slurm will happily run several jobs on the same node. For a job to request a full node (regardless of how many CPU cores it actually uses), it must include

```
#SBATCH --exclusive
```

By default, jobs share nodes and RAM, but not CPU cores/threads.

You can just submit a bunch of small jobs, each requesting a single core. I.e.

```
#SBATCH --nodes=1
#SBATCH --ntasks-per-node=1
#SBATCH --ntasks-per-core=1
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=1
```

(the above is probably more specific than it need be, but it will work).

> Is there any difference from using a shell loop in the script to using `--ntasks`?

Not much, providing your loop launches subprocesses in the background (e.g. using `&`). Having Slurm do the work might be easier, though. You can then call `sbatch` in a loop instead, no `&` required.

> But how would each process know which chunk to compute?

If you launch 100 jobs, can you not just give each task a specific chunk, indexed by an integer? Just include this integer in your job script, and increment it after each submission (`sbatch`). For many jobs, script this rather than do it manually.

There's also array jobs, as  you say, which might be more fitting for your situation. In the end though, there's nothing you cannot achieve by just launching a swarm of small, regular jobs.

Just go for it. Slurm is pretty smart about sharing resources. The dumbest thing you can come up with will probably work. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer! The [documentation of my cluster says that "nodes are exclusively occupied by one job"](https://wiki.vsc.ac.at/doku.php?id=doku:slurm), so I guess this is a SLURM configuration thingy.

Comment: Right, Slurm is very configurable indeed (by the admin). In this case, I suppose you have to do the "parallelization" / "job spawning" yourself, then, as not to waste resources. You can submit a job with 1 task to a node, then spawn as many subprocesses (using `&`) as there are cores on a node. You should wait for for each subprocess using `wait $pid`. It can be a bit painful to set up if you're not used to shell scripting.

Comment: ok thanks! That clarifies things finally. I was extremely confused by reading the cluster documentation and things about SLURM. In the SLURM script, it doesn't make a difference at all, whether I use ntasks and srun in the scrip to start several processes or if I write a loop with & and no srun at all?

Comment: I'm not actually sure `srun` can be used to start multiple parallel processes on its own, i.e. without `&`. I think of `srun` as a Slurm-aware version of `mpiexec`/`mpirun`, though in actuality things are of course more nuanced. Given that you're not using MPI, I would say don't use `srun` at all. It's just one more complication. With Slurm/`sbatch` you just get dropped into a node with `n` cores. You can then spawn `n` processes (`&`) and rest assured that Linux will spread the work load out amongst those available `n` cores. Again though, remember to `wait` on spawned subprocesses.

Comment: That's something I really struggle to understand. Yes, running a script with sbatch, simply executes the code on a node with n cores. Placing a srun in the script does not seem to change anything (but I am not entirely sure if there is a difference). Not sure what `ntasks=5` in the SLURM script and run it with sbatch does exactly but commands are run once on the node. However, if I do `ntasks=5` and `srun echo world` I see the line printed 5 times. Still unsure if processes can really access only one CPU and how it works precisely.

Comment: `srun echo world` runs `echo world` using MPI, with the nodes/cores setup according to the Slurm specifications (`SBATCH`). So 5 times if toy have `#SBATCH --ntasks=5`. All 5 invocations are identical, except for the MPI rank being set to `0`, `1`, `2`, `3` and `4`, respectively. If you're not using MPI however, you cannot utilise this integer to make the 5 invocations perform different work.

Answer (score 1):

> I assume that it is not a good idea to submit a job requesting multiple nodes

Correct. This would prevent you from benefiting from the fact that the computations are independent.

> Can multiple jobs run on the same node?

That depends on the Slurm configuration, namely the [oversubscribe](https://slurm.schedmd.com/slurm.conf.html#OPT_OverSubscribe) and [exclusiveuser](https://slurm.schedmd.com/slurm.conf.html#OPT_ExclusiveUser), and the job parameters with the `--exclusive` option.

> But how can I run multiple computation chunks on one node?

Assuming jobs cannot share a compute node, your submission script will have to distribute the work to the CPUs of the node. There are multiple ways to do that, among which

- using `srun`
- using [GNU Parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/)
  are the most useful in my opinion.

> If I set --ntasks to the number of computation chunks I need to run and --ntasks-per-node to the number of cores on a node, would SLURM automatically spread the processes across nodes?

Yes if and only if you start those processes with `srun`.

> If yes, would these nodes be requested synchronous, i.e. causing a longer queuing time?

Yes if multiple nodes are requested.

Beware that the configuration might prevent you from using all the nodes resources even if it is configured to only allow one job per node. So make sure to specify `--exclusive` and `--mem=0` in your submission script.

> As far as I understand, I can use --ntasks and srun to run a command multiple times (also without use of MPI) on one node. But how would each process know which chunk to compute? Is there something like the env variable SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID for tasks?

Yes, it is named [SLURM_PROCID](https://slurm.schedmd.com/srun.html#OPT_SLURM_PROCID). You can use the value of that variable in the process started with `srun` to differentiate its behaviour.

> Is there any difference from using a shell loop in the script to using --ntasks?

These two options are not mutually exclusive. You can start multiple instances of `srun` each using a portion of the tasks requested in the submission script. Slurm will make sure that the sum of each `srun` instances does is always at most the number of available tasks.

Note that in the accounting, each `srun` invocation`records a *job step*, and that the`SLURM_PROCID`variable is meaningful only among the instances spawned by the same`srun` invocation.

In the context of a full-node reservation, the use of GNU parallel really makes things easier. Some thing like

```
parallel --jobs $SLURM_CPUS_ON_NODE ./myprogram ::: *.csv
```

would run `./myprogram` on every `.csv` file in the directory, with as many parallel processes as the number of CPUs on the node. This other example

```
parallel --jobs $SLURM_CPUS_ON_NODE ./myprogram ::: {1..4} :: {10..20}
```

would start `./myprogram` with two arguments, the first one being taken from 1 -> 4 and the second one from 10 to 20, with all pairwise combinations.

GNU parallel has numerous useful syntaxes to generate a set of parameters for all instances of the program run.